# Can とき function adverbially?

Tags: adverbs

In

> 道を渡るとき、車に気をつけてください

Is there an implicit は being dropped after とき? Or is/can とき function adverbially (so that no particle need be after it, at least not necessarily)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can とき function adverbially?
> Or is/can とき function adverbially (so that no particle need be after it, at least not necessarily)?

Yes, it can. No particle necessarily need to be after it **in your sentence**. (「～ときに...」 has different nuance from 「～とき...」)

An example sentence from [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D/#jn-157586):

> とき【時】
> 10 （行為や状態を表す連体修飾を受けて）
> ㋐ある状態になっている時点や時期。「家に着いた**とき**、母はいなかった」

---

> 道を渡るとき、車に気をつけてください。
> 道を渡るときは、車に気をつけてください。

Both above sound good to me, but

> 道を渡るときに、車に気をつけてください。

doesn't sound natural.

[～ときに + imperative] can be used in a case like this:

> 時間があるときに来てください。(← talking about *when* one should visit.)
> 今度来たときに提出してください。(← talking about *when* one should submit, e.g. as a response to "When should I submit this?")
> <sup>(時間があるとき来てください、今度来たとき提出してください would also be acceptable)</sup>
>
> Compare: 道を渡るとき(は)、車に気をつけてください。(← not talking about when one should be careful, but talking about what one should do when crossing a road.)

Comment: Do you know what a 連体修飾 is? Does it differ from a 連体形?

Comment: @George 「連体形」means **体**言に**連** (つら)なる**形** (the form that connects to a 体言/noun) , and 「連体修飾」means **体**言に**連**なる**修飾** (modifier that connects to a 体言/noun). So 連体修飾 is a word, phrase or clause modifying a noun. 連体修飾 includes 連体詞 (eg あの+人、小さな+猫), 連体形 of a verb, adjective etc. (eg 小さい+猫), relative clause (eg お母さんが作った+カレー), phrase with ～の (eg 山田さんの+車、山田さんからの+手紙).

Answer (score 3):

There is an implicit に dropped after とき. The complete way of saying it should be "道を渡るとき**に**", meaning "**at** the time of crossing roads." とき is a noun, Vとき(V being a verb) means "the time of doing V", which is a noun phrase. You need the particle に (here it should translate to "at") to make this an adverbial phrase: Vときに (***at*** the time of doing V). This particle, as you see here, is often dropped.

You could also argue that we put a は there, but then the focus of the sentence would shift to "道を渡るとき", giving it emphasis, making it the topic of the sentence. With how the sentence is written right now, I'd say it's pretty "neutral", no special emphasis given to the part "道を渡るとき".